# If dependency property is true, then ICommand property should execute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, icommand

Ok, I have the custom control with its style and the view model with the ICommand property in the different files.

CustomControl.cs

```
public class CustomButtons: Control
 {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CmdExecProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CmdExec), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomButtons), 
            new PropertyMetadata(false, ValuePropertyChange));

    public bool CmdExec
    {
      get => (bool)GetValue(CmdExecProperty);
      set => SetValue(CmdExecProperty, value);
    }

    private static void ValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (d is CustomButtons self)
      {
        DataViewModel dataViewModel = (DataViewModel)self.DataContext;

        if (self.CmdExec)
        {
           dataViewModel.ExecuteCommand.Execute(dataViewModel.ExecuteCommand);
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

CustomButtonsStyle.xaml

```
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

  <!--  Control template for a CustomButtons -->
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomButtonsTemplate"
                   TargetType="{x:Type v:CustomButtons}">
    <Grid Width="128"
          d:DesignHeight="200">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="52" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Button x:Name="LoadButton"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Height="50"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Critical,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                        AncestorType={x:Type v:CustomButtons}},
                                          Mode=OneWay}"
              Content="CmndExec"
              IsEnabled="true" />
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>

  <Style x:Key="CustomButtonsStyle"
         TargetType="{x:Type v:CustomButtons}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomButtonsTemplate}" />
  </Style>

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type v:CustomButtons}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomButtonsStyle}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

DataViewModel.cs
The commands are in the file.

```
    private ICommand _executeCommand;

   public ICommand ExecuteCommand
    {
      get
      {
        return _executeCommand
          ?? (_executeCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(ExecuteCommandMethod));
      }
    }
```

Usage

```
 <kit:CustomButtons x:Name="Buttons"
                          CmdExec="True"/>
```

This CustomControl works fine but I want that when CmdExec DepenpencyProperty is True, then the command i.e. ExecuteCommand (command name is used in CustomButtonsStyle.xaml under Button) should execute, regardless the button is pressed or not.

Now the command is perfectly bind with the button, when I press the button, it works fine.

but the issue is that let's say the CmdExec="True", then it should not matter whether the button is press or not, the command should do its work.
I tried doing that in ValueChangeProperty in CustomButton.cs, but still, I am not able to achieve that.

Any help how to solve this issue, when CmdExec is true, the ExecuteCommand ICommand property should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your explanation.
But if you do an analogue of executing your command in XAML, then it should be like this:

```cs
    private static void ValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (d is CustomButtons self &&
          (bool) e.NewValue &&
          self.DataContext is DataViewModel dataViewModel)
      {
          dataViewModel.ExecuteCommand.Execute(self.Critical);
      }
    }
```

**P.S.** There is no complete code, but based on the XAML shown, the command parameter binding better be declared like this:

```xml
      <Button x:Name="LoadButton"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Height="50"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding Critical}"
              Content="CmndExec"
              IsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: The command parameter is not something to worry about it is simply the dialog box that opens for the execute command. It says Yes or No. that's it. @EldHasp

Comment: This is analogous to your XAML.
But the point is different.
Does the `ValuePropertyChanged` method fire when CmdExec transitions from false to true?
If it works, does the command work?

Comment: it fires the CmdExec but, the command does not execute its own, although it executes when I click on the button.

Comment: Most likely this is due to the logic of the command.
Can you describe in detail what happens when the ValuePropertyChanged method is triggered and its further step-by-step (F11) execution?
Does execution go into the if block? Is the Execute (self.Critical) method called? And then the ExecuteCommandMethod method?
The problem may be in the initialization sequence of the elements.
It is possible that the data context has not yet been set when the ValuePropertyChanged method is called.

Comment: you were a great help. I am thinking about how to deal with the command parameter that comes us when a command is executed. 
Now, it works

Comment: thanks it worked I dig your solution and was able to reach the solution, Thanks.